# Is there a way to merge the input and its placeholder classes in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a simple input element as following:

I styled the element and its placeholder text as follows:

```
input {
 height: 40px;
 width: 600px;
}

input::placeholder {
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: #959595;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Can I merge these two into one block in CSS? Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what you mean!

```
// input.css
input, input::placeholder {
  height: 40px;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: #959595;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

I'd recommend using something like SASS for easy control. (variables and such)

```
// input.scss
input {
    height: 40px;
    width: 600px;
    &::placeholder {
        padding: 10px;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        color: #959595;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Will use SASS :)

Comment: It worths mentioning that you're not actually merging the CSS when SASS is used. SASS is just a preprocessor that allows us to structure our CSS code in order to avoid code repetition with handy syntaxis and built-in functions. Once that code is rendered, you will actually get the code you posted on your question. Try yourself by copy/pasting the sass code in here: https://www.sassmeister.com/ and see the output.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with vanilla CSS, but it is with [sass](https://sass-lang.com/guide):

```
input {
 height: 40px;
 width: 600px;

  &::placeholder {
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #959595;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

Sass lets you nest child selectors inside their parents, using `&` to represent the parent. There's more on the sass ampersand on [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)